# Authorize button in swagger ui of FastAPI

Tags: oauth-2.0, fastapi

I am really confused between the need of OAuth2PasswordRequestForm and OAuth2PasswordBearer in below oauth code in Fastapi. I have below two queries

1. who is resposible for autherise button creation in swagger ui?

[image]

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn

fake_users_db = {
    "johndoe": {
        "username": "johndoe",
        "full_name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "hashed_password": "fakehashedsecret",
        "disabled": False,
    }
}

app = FastAPI()
def fake_hash_password(password: str):
    return "fakehashed" + password
    
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
    
class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: Optional[str] = None
    full_name: Optional[str] = None
    disabled: Optional[bool] = None
    
class UserInDB(User):
    hashed_password: str

def get_user(db, username: str):
    if username in db:
        user_dict = db[username]
        return UserInDB(**user_dict)

def fake_decode_token(token):
    # This doesn't provide any security at all
    # Check the next version
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, token)
    return user

async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    print("token value is....%s\n" % token)
    user = fake_decode_token(token)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    return user

async def get_current_active_user(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user
    
@app.post("/token")
async def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user_dict = fake_users_db.get(form_data.username)
    if not user_dict:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    user = UserInDB(**user_dict)
    hashed_password = fake_hash_password(form_data.password)
    if not hashed_password == user.hashed_password:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")

    return {"access_token": user.username, "token_type": "bearer"}
    
@app.get("/protected_hi")
async def protected_hi(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return "Hi! How are you? You are in a protected Zone."
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run('test:app', host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, reload=True)
```

2. when I login by clicking on "Authorize" button, I am able to access protect api named "/protected_hi" however instead of "Authorize" button If I click on "/token" url and fill user/pass. I am not able to access my protected api. Why so? What is the use of "Authorize" button and "/token" url both in swagger UI?  I have already gone through the fastapi docs but could not understand this part.

Answer (score 4):

**Question 1:** The Authorize button appears on the UI when you create a path operation that depends directly or indirectly on OAuth2PasswordBearer, like the example from the documentation:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    ...
async def get_current_active_user(current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]):
    ...
@app.get("/users/me")
async def read_users_me(current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)]):
    ...
```

The "read_users_me" path operation causes the Authorize button to appear because it depends on "get_current_active_user" that depends on "get_current_user" that depends on an instance of "OAuth2PasswordBearer" called "oauth2_scheme".

The UI knows this because it is reading the documentation file of your API ("openapi.json", located at "hostname:port/openapi.json" as in "localhost:8000/openapi.json") that is generated from your code automatically for you. If you look inside the file you will see mentions of "OAuth2PasswordBearer", and they disappear if you comment out the "read_users_me" path operation function and decorator.

Bear in mind that the Swagger UI is only a development aid, for debugging purposes, and not for real production uses.

**Question 2:** When you click the Authorize button and log in using it, the UI will receive the token back from your API and will store it somewhere and provide it as needed for the endpoints that require it.

If you open the developer tools panel of your preferred browser, you can see the requests being made in the network tab as you press the Execute buttons on the UI, and if you look at the Request Headers section, you shall see a header called "Authorization" with a value of "Bearer" followed by the token.

When you simply execute the "/token" manually in the UI, you get the token back from your API but it is not automatically stored and provided when needed, that is the key difference between the two.

As for the uses of them both, you could use the "/token" to test many login attempts and the button to perform a login once and keep the token stored to test other endpoints that need a token.

**Edit:** To prevent the issue where invalid credentials are accepted by your API and return some kind of wrong token that is then stored by the UI, make sure to perform some kind of validation on the credentials inside the login path operation function and raise an HTTPException before returning the token if they are not valid, like this example from the documentation:

```
if not hashed_password == user.hashed_password:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
```

Answer (score 0):

1st question: swagger backend consumes the code you write, and produces what is called "documentation", which is not a production GUI, so that button is there only for help.

The difference is:

- The first one: takes a username, and a password sends them to the route for authentication, takes the result, and store it in the navigator storage, to send it in the header with every request you send to the API, ( which is the same thing the frontend engineer do)
- The second one: is a route just like anything else, it takes data, and it return back data, in your case, it takes username and password, and it gives back a token, you made such route because REST is stateless, and the front end is what should be responsible for customizing that API, and storing the token how ever they like to send it later every time they need to access a protected route.

Comment: regarding #1 which route does it take? i am facing an issue that is when i click on the authorize button it pops up a form and if i provide invalid credentials it saves it